# Handbook of proofs

Tags: mathematics, book-recommendation

Do you know any handbook where original proofs of  mathematicians' of the past theorems and facts are in modern notation? For example, for the Archimedean spiral etc

Comment: Aigner and Ziegler's [Proofs from the Book](https://www.amazon.ca/Proofs-BOOK-Martin-Aigner/dp/3662572648/ref=sr_1_1?crid=Q8CUQ75CGGOE&keywords=proofs+from+the+book&qid=1589830013&sprefix=proofs+fr%2Caps%2C280&sr=8-1) includes some original proofs, but mostly concerns what are considered to be the most beautiful proofs of major theorems, often including multiple proofs.  (Original proofs are often considered "mirror shy".)

Comment: You can not have *original* proofs in modern notation. They were originally given using conceptions different from modern ones, so once they are modernized they are no longer original. Most history of mathematics textbooks, e.g. [Burton's](https://jontalle.web.engr.illinois.edu/uploads/298/HistoryMath-Burton.85.pdf), would give you modernized versions, sometimes with some indications of how they differ from the originals. It would help if you specify what subject and/or time period you are interested in.

Comment: @Conifold I'm interested in mathematics of Ancient Greece. Thank you!